# Ansible compare stdout with a variable

Tags: ansible

I have a questions since I am giving crazy. I want to compare stdout result to one variable storaged in my vars file.
For instance, instead of using the variable but the string ( The IP 22.22.2.2), it works:

Nets.yml

```
- List_nets_find: 
  - host 22.22.2.2
```

Playbook:

```
---
- name: Black List
  hosts: routers
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
   - vars/Nets.yml

  tasks:    

   - name: Check the object-group
     ios_command:
      commands: 
       - command: "show object-group BLOCK-LIST" 
     register: output
     tags:
     - see
   - debug:
      msg: included
     when: output.stdout is search('22.22.2.2')
     tags:
     - see
```

Result:

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [Router1]
ok: [Router3] => {
    "msg": "included"
}
ok: [Router2] => {
    "msg": "included"
}
```

But instead of using the string, I use the Variable, it does not work.

```
- name: Black List
  hosts: routers
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
   - vars/Nets.yml

  tasks:    

   - name: Check the object-group
     ios_command:
      commands: 
       - command: "show object-group BLOCK-LIST" 
     register: output
     tags:
     - see
   - debug:
      msg: included
     when: output.stdout is search('{{List_net_find}}')
     tags:
     - see
```

This is the error:

```
fatal: [Router1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'output.stdout is search('{{List_net_find}}')' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (output.stdout is search('{{List_net_find}}')): 'List_net_find' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ansible/Ios_ACL_LAB/object-group.yml': line 23, column 10, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n         - see\n       - debug:\n         ^ here\n"}
fatal: [Router3]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'output.stdout is search('{{List_net_find}}')' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (output.stdout is search('{{List_net_find}}')): 'List_net_find' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ansible/Ios_ACL_LAB/object-group.yml': line 23, column 10, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n         - see\n       - debug:\n         ^ here\n"}
fatal: [Router2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'output.stdout is search('{{List_net_find}}')' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (output.stdout is search('{{List_net_find}}')): 'List_net_find' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ansible/Ios_ACL_LAB/object-group.yml': line 23, column 10, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n         - see\n       - debug:\n         ^ here\n"}
```

Any suggestion? or other way to do it?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `vars/Nets.yml` does not declare a **variable** named `List_nets_find`, it declares an anonymous list whose first element is a `dict` whose only key is named `List_nets_find`

If you want a variable named that, then change `- List_nets_find:` to be `List_nets_find:`

---

Separately, the next question you are going to ask is "why does my search not match anything" and that's because `List_nets_find` is a **list** of str, so you will want to change that test to be `output.stdout is search(List_nets_find | map("regex_escape") | join("|"))`, using [the `regex_escape` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters) to turn those strings into something that can be safely fed into a `search` alternation

Comment: Thanks so much! it works
I have a question. What does it means map("regex_escape")?. Sorry I am a very beginner in Ansible and the idea to use map("regex_escape") | join ("|"), as far as I know is to separate the list of str?
Thanks again

Comment: Because `search` is for _a_ regular expression, but you have a _list_ of just normal `str`, you'll need to fold the list into a single regular expression. The `|` is regex-ese for "or", so if your list was `["alpha", "beta"]` then the regex that checks for membership in that list is `alpha|beta`. However, regexes are not strings, they have their own syntax; specifically, the `.` means "match any character" so your `host 22.22.2.2` if just fed into `host 22.22.2.2|host 11.11.1.1` would match `host 22922x2!2` which could be fine but is a needless risk when we have `regex_escape` available to us